# Using WIndows 7 SR1

Tags: windows-7, batch-file, user-profiles

I work in a company that does net support for 20 different schools.  While working on accounts I might log my "test" computer in 10 different domains in one day.

After a few days a login goes from 30 seconds to 5 minutes.

Then if I clear out all the profiles by right click computer, properties, advanced system settings, User Profile Settings, delete one by one.

Then clear their c:\user\jdoe folders.

Is there a script that can delete all the profiles, and all the network folders?

Like:

```
net user * /delete
```

or

```
for %%a in (***) do (
   net  user  %%a  /del
   rd  /s  /q  "C:\UserProfiles\%%a"
)
```

but I need to replace `***` with each user.

Comment: You might want to adjust the title, it seems to have nothing in common with the actual question.

Comment: I have no idea what "Windows 7 SR 1" is

Comment: Possibly SP1???

Answer (score 1):

#### Is there a script that can delete all the profiles, and all the network folders?

You can user `wmic useraccount get name` to get a list of user names and `for /f` to process the list.

**Warning**:

- Please review the following script carefully. I believe it does exactly what you ask for.
- Not tested as I don't want to delete the local users on my laptop.
- If you are happy with the output then remove the appropriate `echo` commands and run the script again.

**DeleteUsers.cmd:**

```
@echo off
setlocal 
rem skip first line
rem use findstr to strip blank lines from wmic output
for /f "usebackq skip=1" %%i in (`wmic useraccount get name ^| findstr /r /v "^$"`) do (
  echo net user %%i /del
  echo rd /s /q "C:\Users\%%i"
  )
endlocal
```

Example Output:

```
F:\test>wmic useraccount get name
Name
Administrator
DavidPostill
Guest
ntp


F:\test>deleteusers
net user Administrator /del
rd /s /q "C:\Users\Administrator"
net user DavidPostill /del
rd /s /q "C:\Users\DavidPostill"
net user Guest /del
rd /s /q "C:\Users\Guest"
net user ntp /del
rd /s /q "C:\Users\ntp"

F:\test>
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [net](http://ss64.com/nt/net.html)  - The NET Command is used to manage network resources.
- [rd](http://ss64.com/nt/rd.html) - Delete folder(s).
- [wmic](http://ss64.com/nt/wmic.html) - Windows Management Instrumentation Command.